# Access controls on other windows - 2

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7

I wrote a Delphi program 4 or 5 years ago, now, I have .exe file, but I lost my source. I'm a C# programmer (beginner :D) now. for some resons, I need to change the text of a textBox in my Delphi program and press a button by my new c# program. How can I access to the controls on another application's window?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908820/access-controls-on-other-windows), but I confused :(