# How to get message of another process MessageBox?

Tags: c#, c++, window, messagebox

Another application sometimes shows MessageBox with title "Test" and some message inside of MessageBox body, how can i from another application (writed on C++ or C# whatever) get this message and then close it? Code in C#:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,uint Msg,int wParam,int lParam);
public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) // just test cycle
{
     IntPtr window = FindWindow(null, "Test");
     if (window != IntPtr.Zero) // ok we found it!
     {
          // code that reads MessageBox message?
          .....
          // work is done, closing
          SendMessage((int)window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
          break;
     }
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Can you help me with this problem? How can i do it?

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908820/access-controls-on-other-windows).

**Choice 1:**

> You can use an API like [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) to access other windows controls.

**Choice 2:**

> you should use Windows APIs like EnumWindow or FindWindow then use
>   EnumChildWindows API to find the controls in the target window, like
>   the textbox you are looking for, then the API [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> have a look here for some ideas: [Why is EnumChildWindows skipping
>   children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014190/why-is-enumchildwindows-skipping-children) also search for these APIs names here in Stack Overflow and
>   you will find many examples...

**Choice 3:**

> I found this api which may allow you to complete your task :
>   http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/56171/download.aspx

Comment: Choice #3 link is dead - do you have any other details that could help in finding that download?