# Can I launch DotNet's OpenFileDialog in C:\Users\Public\Documents?

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

**Is there a way to launch the `OpenFileDialog` in the `C:\Users\Public\Documents` folder?**

I am writing a C# application, using the DotNet framework.  I am trying to launch an `OpenFileDialog`, with an `InitialDirectory` of `"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\"` and a `FileName` of `"world.txt"`.  Unfortunately, the `OpenFileDialog` is putting me in the `Documents` shortcut instead of into `C:\Users\Public\Documents` .

**Expected results**
I expect to see the OpenFileDialog open, with the top textbox showing `> This PC > Windows7_OS (C:) > Users > Public > Documents` and the bottom textbox showing `world.txt` .  I expect that if I click in the top textbox, it will show `C:\Users\Public\Documents` .

**Actual results**
The OpenFileDialog opens.  The top textbox shows `> This PC > Documents` and the bottom textbox shows `world.txt` .  If I click in the top textbox, it shows `Documents` .  The displayed folder contents are **not** the same as the contents of `C:\Users\Public\Documents` .

**Things I have tried**
I have stopped the code in the Visual Studio debugger after the following line of code:
`OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();`

In the Immediate Window, I have executed code such as the following:

```
dlg.FileName = "world.txt"  
? dlg.FileName  
dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\NonExistentDirectory\\";  
dlg.ShowDialog();  
dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";  
dlg.ShowDialog();  
dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\";  
dlg.ShowDialog(); 
dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\";  
dlg.ShowDialog(); 
dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\";  
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

I cancel out of each dialog.

I used `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe` to `cd` between `C:\` and `C:\Users\` and `C:\Users\Public` and `C:\Users\Public\Documents\` .

**Results of things I have tried**

- When `dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\NonExistentDirectory\\"` , the dialog's folder initially displays as `This PC > Documents > Visual Studio 2015 > Projects > SimpleGame > Controller > bin > Debug"` .  Clicking in the textbox causes it to display `C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SimpleGame\Controller\bin\Debug` .  I therefore assume that `OpenFileDialog` silently handles an invalid `InitialDirectory` by not changing directories.  In this case, it is defaulting to my project's assembly's bin's `Debug` folder.
- When `dlg.InitialDirectory` is `"C:\\"` or `"C:\\Users\\"` or `"C:\\Users\\Public\\"` the dialog behaves as expected.  Clicking in the top textbox produces `C:\` or `C:\Users` or `C:\Users\Public` respectively.
- When `dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\"` the dialog behaves incorrectly.  The top textbox shows `> This PC > Documents` and the bottom textbox shows `world.txt` .  If I click in the top textbox, it shows `Documents` .  The displayed folder contents are **not** the same as the contents of `C:\Users\Public\Documents` .
- Using `cmd.exe` lets me `cd` between the folders as expected, including into `C:\Users\Public\Documents` .

**My environment**
I am running Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, using Microsoft Visual C# 2015.  My operating system is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: might be a privilege thing ? have you tried running vs as administrator ?

Comment: I am also using Windows 10 Pro and can confirm this behavior.  Note that if you use `dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\";` or `dlg.InitialDirectory = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Documents\\";` then the dialog will open to the corresponding library.  If you specify the path to a directory that is a part of a custom library, however, then the dialog opens to that physical directory.  Perhaps the dialog is trying to be "smart" when opened to a directory that is part of a library with a [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the directory using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)`?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis -- `dlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDo‌​cuments); dlg.ShowDialog();` also produces the unwanted `Documents` .  The `GetFolderPath` was `"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents"` .

Comment: @Noctis -- I have all the permissions I need to create/modify/read/write/list *et cetera* files in the `C:\Users\Public\Documents` folder.  I can do so using `cmd.exe` .

Comment: It's 2022 and I'm having the same issue! If I set the initial directory to `C:\Users\SomeUser\Pictures` it puts me in `Libraries\Pictures` instead of `ThisPC\Pictures`. Yes, adding `dlg.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false` does open to the correct folder, but it's ugly and *shouldn't be necessary*. Apparently Microsoft doesn't see this as a bug?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog you can set:

```
dialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
```

The dialog will look a little dated/flat/"old school" but it does at least display the correct contents!

Answer (score 2):

although as stated by Silver, this is a bug but can be roughly bypassed using SendMessage API with WM_SETTEXT on a different thread although hackish *to say the least*, it will most likely work.

i've put together some dirty code snippet using [NSGaga's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198186/3933927) to show a proof of concept, this raw example should not be used as is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            //start a thread to change the dialog path just before displaying it to the user
            Thread posThread = new Thread(setDialogPath);
            posThread.Start();

            //display dialog to the user
            DialogResult dr = dlg.ShowDialog();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, string lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, Win32Callback callback, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        private void setDialogPath()
        {
            const string FULL_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents";

            //messages
            const int WM_SETTEXT = 0xC;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            //enter key code
            const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;

            //dialog box window handle
            IntPtr _window_hwnd;

            //how many attempts to detect the window
            int _attempts_count = 0;

            //get the dialog window handle
            while ((_window_hwnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "Open")) == IntPtr.Zero)
                if (++_attempts_count > 100)
                    return;
                else
                    Thread.Sleep(500); //try again

            //in it - find the path textbox's handle.
            var hwndChild = EnumAllWindows(_window_hwnd, "Edit").FirstOrDefault();

            //set the path
            SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_SETTEXT, 0, FULL_PATH);

            //apply the path (send 'enter' to the textbox)
            PostMessage(hwndChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
            PostMessage(hwndChild, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
        }


        public delegate bool Win32Callback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

        private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
        {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
            List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
            if (list == null)
                throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
            list.Add(handle);
            return true;
        }

        public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
        {
            List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
            GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
            try
            {
                Win32Callback childProc = new Win32Callback(EnumWindow);
                EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                    listHandle.Free();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string GetWinClass(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;
            StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(100);
            IntPtr result = GetClassName(hwnd, classname, classname.Capacity);
            if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
                return classname.ToString();
            return null;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumAllWindows(IntPtr hwnd, string childClassName)
        {
            List<IntPtr> children = GetChildWindows(hwnd);
            if (children == null)
                yield break;
            foreach (IntPtr child in children)
            {
                if (GetWinClass(child) == childClassName)
                    yield return child;
                foreach (var childchild in EnumAllWindows(child, childClassName))
                    yield return childchild;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hackish, but doable

Comment: I have adapted this code, and added it to my program.  I seem to have a run-time caching problem.  (I have noticed that other features of my program are very slow when I start the program, and become faster later.)  Within a given run of the program, the first time I open a file using this code, the `OpenFileDialog` still goes into `Documents` .  Subsequent times that I open a file work correctly, and `OpenFileDialog` goes into the `C:\Users\Public\Documents` folder.

Comment: When I build in Release mode, this code works intermittently. As I mentioned previously, this code works for me in Debug mode after the first use. In Release mode, it does not work on the first use; it works on the second use; and it works intermittently on subsequent uses.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **it is impossible!**

You can see in the following link that it is a bug in .net framework :(
[msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7559bbe-fc4f-4554-a9b6-ef72d181f7d1/openfiledialog-will-not-show-initaldirectorycuserspublicpublic-documents?forum=csharpgeneral)
you can find in the last comment:

> It is hard to believe but:
>
> It is a bug and nothing else.

Comment: I believe this can be done using Win32 SendMessage API with WM_SETTEXT on a different thread, although hackish to say the least, it will most likely work.

Comment: if you will post a working solution I will upvote it and delete my answer... (but if you fail please upvote mine)

Comment: @silver -- Please do not delete your answer.  I am happy to have two different useful answers, and upvote them both.

Comment: The [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7559bbe-fc4f-4554-a9b6-ef72d181f7d1/openfiledialog-will-not-show-initaldirectorycuserspublicpublic-documents?forum=csharpgeneral) (in this answer) suggests that perhaps 25 paths are likely to have this problem.

Comment: I have written a check to see if the path is known to have this problem.  If so, I set `dlg.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false` per @DavidHollinshead's suggestion.  If I run into problems with any of the other 24 likely problematic paths, I can generalize the test to deal with them all.

Answer (score 1):

You would think the obvious answer would be to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDo‌​‌​cuments`, but that seems to do the exact same thing as `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDo‌​‌​cuments` on Windows 10. This must be a bug in .NET!

I ran into this issue today and found a solution that worked for me, and might work for someone else. Just add a subfolder to the Public Documents, and then use that as the initial directory instead. It is probably better practice to be storing your stuff in an application-specific subfolder instead of just at the root anyway. Like this:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments, "SomeSubfolder").
```

Comment: Does this give you "C:\Users\Public\Documents\SomeSubfolder\" ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does! Without adding a subfolder, CommonDocuments just plain won't work the way you expect. But as soon as you add in the subfolder, you get exactly what you desire